# Firefox add-ons with a rich look and feel

Tags: firefox, browser-addons, user-interface

I am looking for examples of the "best looking" Firefox add-ons. By "best looking" I mean usable and stylish look and feel. I am not necessarily looking for "must have" add-ons but for examples of how rich an add-on can be.

One add-on per answer, please.

Answer (score 6):

[Cooliris](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/5579) is a visually appealing image browsing addon with a unique mouse interface.

[image: Cooliris]

Answer (score 5):

[Locationbar²](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/4014) - it's not very *stylish*, but it is very *usable*.

Relevant screenshots:

a) cleaner URLs

[image]

b) each part acts as a separate link, my mouse is over 'questions'

[image]

c) available options

[image]

Comment: looks nice, i'll install it

Answer (score 4):

**Firefox 3.7 Theme**

[image]

This is based on [Mozilla's design mockups](http://lifehacker.com/5319301/mozilla-releases-initial-design-mockups-for-firefox-37) for Firefox 3.7.

Installing this theme isn't very simple. You'll need to first install the [All-Glass](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/12181) Firefox extension for the Aero effects, the [Personal Menu](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/3895) extension to hide the menubar and add the Tools button, the [Stylish](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/2108) extension for a tweak that fixes the text, and then drag the mockup theme's *.jar file into the add-ons window to install it.

For detailed instructions: http://lifehacker.com/5322073/firefox-37-theme-makes-your-browser-look-awesome

For the Firefox 3.7 theme: http://boneyardbrew.deviantart.com/art/Firefox-3-7-Mockup-Redux-2-0-130502568

Comment: cool! i just saw the mockups for Firefox 4. Its going the Chrome way!!

Answer (score 2):

After thinking a little, the best look and feel can only be achieved with extensions that let you tweak them (i.e., everyone has preferences.) So my pick goes for [Stylish](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/2108).

It lets you apply CSS to almost anything that can be represented in Firefox, even XUL!

An example of it, I've messed with my history menu to make it unique, here is how it looks after some work (CSS3 on the XUL omg omg):

[image]

Okay, it's not a full-blown application. but Stylish and [userstyles.org](http://userstyles.org) are for CSS what [Greasemonkey](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/2108) and [userscripts.org](http://userscripts.org) are for [JavaScript](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JavaScript), so possibilities for a "rich look and feel" are almost unlimited.

Answer (score 1):

I happen to like the [Brief](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/4578) feed reader and it seems fairly slick to me.

[image: screen capture of of Firefox extension Brief]

Answer (score 0):

**[FoxTab](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/8879)**

[image]

FoxTab lets you cycle through your tabs in interesting ways.